# How to plot ROC curve and precision-recall curve from BinaryClassificationMetrics

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I was trying to plot ROC curve and Precision-Recall curve in graph. The points are generated from the Spark Mllib BinaryClassificationMetrics. By following the following Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

```
[(1.0,1.0), (0.0,0.4444444444444444)] Precision
[(1.0,1.0), (0.0,1.0)] Recall
[(1.0,1.0), (0.0,0.6153846153846153)] - F1Measure    
[(0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,0.4444444444444444)]- Precision-Recall curve
[(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0)] - ROC curve
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you have a similar problem to what I experienced. You need to either flip your parameters to the Metrics constructor or perhaps pass in the probability instead of the prediction. So, for example, if you are using the `BinaryClassificationMetrics` and a `RandomForestClassifier`, then according to [this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-classification-regression.html) (under outputs) there is "prediction" and "probability".

Then initialize your Metrics thus:

```
    new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionsWithResponse
      .select(col("probability"),col("myLabel"))
      .rdd.map(r=>(r.getAs[DenseVector](0)(1),r.getDouble(1))))
```

With the DenseVector call used to extract the probability of the 1 class.

As for actual plotting, that's up to you (many fine tools for that), but at least you will get more than 1 point on you curve (besides the endpoints).

And in case it's not clear:

`metrics.roc().collect()` will give you the data for the ROC curve: Tuples of: (false positive rate, true positive rate).