# Common way to plot a ROC Curve

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, roc

I'm trying to obtain ROC Curve for GBTClassifier.

One way is to reuse BinaryClassificationMetrics, however the path given in the documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html) provides only 4 values for the ROC Curve, like:

```
[0.0|0.0]
[0.0|0.9285714285714286]
[1.0|1.0]
[1.0|1.0]
```

Another way is to use the "probability" column instead of "prediction". However, in case of `GBTClassifier` I don't have it and this solution works mostly for `RandomForestClassifier`.

[How to plot ROC curve and precision-recall curve from BinaryClassificationMetrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207990/how-to-plot-roc-curve-and-precision-recall-curve-from-binaryclassificationmetric)

So what is the general/common way to get a ROC curve with enough points for an arbitrary classifier?